# creating conditional array using iopart

Tags: amsmath, cases

I need to write a conditional equation using iopart.cls, a class that doesn't work with amsmath. Usually I'd use the cases environment from amsmath like so:

```
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{sgn}(t) =
\begin{cases}
    1, & \text{if $t>0$}.\\
    -1, & \text{if $t<0$}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Unfortunately, I can't do this in iopart, and have failed to find any way to do it thus far. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I just solved my own question by messing around on the codecogs equation editor- I just made my own conditional array thusly:

```
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{sgn}(t) = \left\{  \begin{array}{r@{\quad}cr} 
1 & \mathrm{if} & t > 0 \\  
-1 &  \mathrm{if} & t < 0   
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The `iopart` document class does not seem to be available on the CTAN. Could you point to a depository from where it might be obtained?

Comment: The iopart infor can be found here: http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Iopart

Comment: the spacing between "if" and "$t>0$ will look off with this setup unless you adjust the amount of intercolumn whitespace, which is governed by the parameter `\arraycolsep`.

Comment: Edited my fix accordingly, thanks- it looks great now!

Comment: By resetting `\arraycolsep` globally, you're losing the wide space that's conventionally inserted between the result part and condition part of the statement. To fix that, you should insert somethinglike `@{\quad}` between the first `r` and the middle `c`. Note also that `\bigg\{` may be OK for a statement with exactly two rows but will fail if you have three or more rows. You should use `\left\{`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a do-it-yourself version of the `cases` environment. By specifying only two columns in the `array`, you'll get a normal interword space between "if" and "$t>0".

[image]

```
\documentclass{iopart}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}} % text mode "l" in an "array"
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{sgn}(t) =
\left\{ \begin{array}{@{\kern2.5pt}lL}
    \hfill 1 & if $t>0$.\\
    \hfill 0 & if $t=0$,\\
          -1 & if $t<0$.
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'd upvote your comment, but I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: Wouldn't an `r` column be better?

Comment: @crubster  - Hopefully a few more people will upvote your posting, giving you enough rep points to do your own upvoting. :-)

Comment: @egreg - I did think about this too, but in the end I chose to go with the `cases` setup (which, as you know, uses `l` for the first column). If the OP's use case calls for the use of `r` for the first column of the `array`, I trust he/she can adapt the code without too much effort.