# How to use \cases in iopart document class

Tags: amsmath, cases

The iopart document class defines the following in the `iopart.cls` file

```
\def\cases#1{%
     \left\{\,\vcenter{\def\\{\cr}\normalbaselines\openup1\jot\m@th%
     \ialign{\strut$\displaystyle{##}\hfil$&\tqs
     \rm##\hfil\crcr#1\crcr}}\right.}%
```

Is this a substitute for `amsmath`'s `cases` environment? How do I use it? The definition appears nowhere else in the file.

The question of how to implement a cases environment manually has already been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209176/creating-conditional-array-using-iopart). I am wondering if this is still required, given the age of that post.

Comment: The `iopart` document class was last updated in 1996. Why are you using it?

Comment: Good point... it is still the preferred format here: https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/publishing-support/authors/authoring-for-journals/writing-journal-article/. I don't have to use it, I just like the defaults it uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definition of `\cases` (which is not an environment) is a modification of the one in the LaTeX kernel, which in turn is essentially the same as in plain TeX.

By the way, commands such as `\rm` and `\bf` are obsolete and have been deprecated for almost three decades.

There is a very simple way to be able to load `amsmath` along with `iopart`. I'll also use a trick in order to compare the result of `iopart`'s `\cases` and `amsmath`'s `cases`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}

% for using amsmath
\expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname\relax

%%% This is just to compare the results
\let\iopartcases\cases
%%%

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

In the following display I'll be using \verb|\cases| as
defined by \verb|iopart| in order to check the differences
\[
f(x)=\iopartcases{1 & abc \\ 0 & uvw}
\]
The following display will use \verb|cases| as defined by
\verb|amsmath| in order to check the differences
\[
f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & abc \\ 0 & uvw \end{cases}
\]
Now we can decide which one to use.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer the way `iopart` does, you can define a `iopcases` environment (I'd not override `amsmath` one).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}

% for using amsmath
\expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname\relax

%%% This is just to compare the results
\let\iopartcases\cases
%%%

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcases{iopcases}{\tqs}
 {$\m@th\displaystyle##$\hfil}
 {##\hfil}
 {\lbrace}
 {.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

In the following display I'll be using \verb|\cases| as
defined by \verb|iopart| in order to check the differences
\[
f(x)=\iopartcases{1 & abc \\ 0 & uvw}
\]
The following display will use \verb|iopcases| as defined
above in order to check the differences
\[
f(x)=\begin{iopcases} 1 & abc \\ 0 & uvw \end{iopcases}
\]
Now we can decide which one to use.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you want the thin space like `iopart` does? Change into

```
\makeatletter
\newcases{iopcases}{\tqs}
 {$\m@th\displaystyle\,##$\hfil}
 {##\hfil}
 {\lbrace}
 {.}
\makeatother
```

and you'll get

[image]

I wouldn't use `iopart` for private purposes. There are several other classes that don't need tricks in order to use basic tools for typesetting mathematics.