# Equation left-aligned (not centre aligned) in iopart.cls (IOP Publishing)

Tags: equations, alignment

I have the following issue preparing a document for publication using the IOP LaTeX template for journal articles (see [the IOP LaTeX page here](https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/questions/latex-template/)).

By default, the equations align left. After some research, the author guidelines describe this on page 13 (section 5.5), however except for arrayed/multi-line equations, they do not describe a method for central alignment. See below two example equations and the output. I've parsed the iopart.cls file, and I can't seem to work out how to change it to centre-aligned.
Any ideas?

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Amp1}
\nabla \times {\bf H} = {\bf J}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Fara1}
\nabla \times {\bf E} =  - \frac{\partial(\mu {\bf H})}{\partial t}
\end{equation}
```

[image: Image of equation output]

---

**Please note, for anyone unfamiliar with IOP Publishing**

*It is okay to edit the class*, as the manuscript will be sent to IOP's LaTeX editors, and formatted for the specific journal (in this case SUST), after the peer-review and editor accept for publication. You may submit a manuscript for publication in any format (and in my experience it has not affected publication speed) or reformat exactly as iopart.cls generates *post peer-review*.

---

Comment: unrelated, but don't use `\bf` in latex

Answer (score 1):

You can load amsmath with its default centred layout, but you need to avoid a few clashes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{iopart}
\expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname\undefined
\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname\undefined
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

aaa
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Amp1}
\nabla \times \mathbf{H} = \mathbf{J}
\end{equation}

bbb
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Fara1}
\nabla \times \mathbf{E} =  - \frac{\partial(\mu \mathbf{H})}{\partial t}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640747/4427 for the initial trick.